# Saving the state of a page with content loaded via Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress, browser-history, history.js

**Background**

I'm loading my projects (posts) via Ajax into a `div` on the front page whenever a project link is clicked. The response is fine and I've managed to get `pushState()` to work wonderfully.

**Problem**

I'm having problems saving the state when the project has been loaded.

When a project loads, the url changes from `example.com` to `example.com/title-of-post`. I want to save the state when the project has been loaded (`example.com/title-of-post`) so that when a user inputs `example.com/title-of-post` into the address bar, the page loads with that project loaded in the `div`.

*Note: `example.com/title-of-post` used to redirect to `example.com/projects/title-of-post` but I made an `htaccess` redirect on that.*

**Example**

[This page](http://themetrust.com/demos/reveal/#dubai) is a good example of what I'm trying to achieve, although I'd rather not use hashtags in the url. Notice how when you visit that url, the respective project (dubai) is already loaded.

**What I have done (using History.js)**

```
$('.post-link').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var post_id = $(this).data('id'),
        projectTitle = $(this).data('title'), 
        projectSlug = $(this).data('slug'), 
        ajaxURL = site.ajaxurl; 

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: ajaxURL,
        context: this,
        data: {'action': 'load-content', post_id: post_id },
        success: function(response) {

            // Load the response from the Ajax call
            $('#project-container').html(response);

            // Make history
            var stateDataObj = { project: projectSlug };
            History.pushState(stateDataObj, site.title, site.url + '/' + projectSlug);

            // Revert to our previously saved state
            History.Adapter.bind(window, 'statechange', function(){ // Note: We are using statechange instead of popstate
                var State = History.getState(); // Note: We are using History.getState() instead of event.state
                var stateDataObj = State.data;
                $(this).closest('#main').find('#project-container').html(response);
            });

            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

**This is my WordPress loop.**

```
<div id="project-wrapper">
    <a href="#" class="close-button">&times;</a>
    <div id="project-container"></div>
</div>

<div id="projects-list">

<!-- Start the loop -->
<?php $home_query = new WP_Query('post_type=projects');

while($home_query->have_posts()) : $home_query->the_post(); ?>

    <article class="project">
        <?php the_post_thumbnail( 'home-thumb' ); ?>
        <div class="overlay">
            <a class="post-link expand" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" data-id="<?php the_ID(); ?>" data-title="<?php the_title(); ?>" data-slug="<?php global $post; echo $post->post_name; ?>">+</a>
        </div>
    </article>

<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php wp_reset_postdata(); // reset the query ?>

</div><!-- #projects-list -->
```

Comment: unfortunately, it will try and resolve the address using the rewrite rules already in place. So you could add a rewrite rule to redirect to the page you want and insert code to read the url and load the project you want.

Comment: Ok, I can make a rewrite rule with `htaccess`, but how would I load the project I want by reading the url? That's the part I'm stuck on. I tried setting the state right after the successful Ajax response, but I'm doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see its the url that the problem. Its resolved before the browser loads so hence using url locations rather than query vars is more difficult.

But to do this, Get the current url using excluding the hostname using `$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]` then you can match this to whatever project you want to load and load using php.

You will need to do this a little differently than a rewrite rule. You will need a function hooked into init to catch the url before it tries to load the url and redirect to the frontpage . You will also need to pass the url information along session or cookie.

If you were just to use a query var `?name=page` you could skip the redirect etc. And your save state would work with a simple js function. Hopefully i have changed your mind :)

Comment: Well, I think you've convinced me to go the query var route. If it's something like `?project=title-of-project` I think I'd be satisfied. But how would I go about doing that? Does this have anything to do with setting the `rewrite` argument in my custom post types function to `false`? Right now it's set to `'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'projects', 'with_front' => false),`. I don't know if that matters.

Comment: something like `$nameofpost = $_GET['project'];  echo '<script> projectName=<?php echo $nameofpost; ?> you can then load the post using your ajax function. Or use php to do it (prob better). You can leave rewrite alone, its not what you need to change but you need the content directly accessible somewhere for seo (make sure its on a sitemap. Its not perfect but better than not having the content available for robots at all)